# What word could I replace "importantly" with in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms, adverbs, sentence

I am looking for a synonym to the word "importantly" in this sentence (as well as other grammar tips because this sentence is messing with my brain):

> "Perhaps more importantly, I learned the importance of the qualities of true friends, who were always there to support me."

Comment: _Significantly_ or _Crucially_ could replace "importantly".

Comment: Your sentence would sound better if it starts by "Most of all, I learned ...". Also, to simplify the text, you may choose between "I learned the importance [or worth] of true friends" or "I appreciated the qualities of true friends".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it sounds strange to you is because you are using **important** twice.

If I were to write this sentence, I would keep the word **importantly** and replace **important**.

**Perhaps more importantly, I learned how significant the qualities of my true friends were, and how supportive they could be in times of crisis.**

Comment: I agree with this; another option for the second part would be "I learned to value the qualities of... "

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest 'saliently':

> Of immaterial things, qualities, etc.: Standing out from the rest; prominent, conspicuous ....

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you should use the adjective important not the adverb importantly.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit more, to help justify your claim? **Specifically** (hint), *why* would an adjective be more appropriate?